# javascript and jquery plugin together on document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi in my ruby on rails application I am using a javascript player inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){ }
```

and now I want is to use a carousel slider javascript in same page, but the js slider not working until I remove the player javascript If I remove the player.js or just remove the $(document).ready(function(){} lines the slider works but the player wont works , what causes the problem ?

I am using player.js as separate javascript file and slider.js as inline is this cause any problem?

Answer (score 1):

did you consider closing the .ready function properly?

Comment: yes I have re checked that now too, I am using player.js as separate javascript file and slider.js as inline is this cause any problem?

Comment: It might. Try placing everything externally.

Answer (score 1):

try to place your js slider code before including player.js and its code.

Comment: I am using player.js as separate javascript file and slider.js as inline is this cause any problem?

Comment: No,this will not cause problem. but as you include player.js ,some function may getting conflicts, so just place your inline slider code then include player.js , hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok but the think is in ruby on rails the js files are included in assets at the time of starting itself there is no way of including inline js before itself :(

Comment: okay, can you just tell what error exactly you are getting in console??

Comment: I am not getting any error simply it does not shows anything until I remove player.js or document.ready line